# Reading a file in Python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm trying to access a .txt file in my root account to open and read in python. My code looks like this:

```
>>> path = 'root/unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt'
>>> read = open(path,'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    read = open(path,'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'root/unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt'
```

I've also tried several variations of this with no such luck. Including:

`path = 'unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt'` and `path = 'enrollment_fact.txt'`

Comment: Can you do an ls of the file? Might be a permission problem

Comment: Full paths start with a slash, it should be `/root/unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt`, you can test that by doing `ls /root/unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt` on your terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is incorrect. Absolute paths need to start with a slash for the root directory. Your path should look like this:

```
path = '/root/unpackedFiles/enrollment_fact.txt'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> path = 'ports.txt'                                          
>>> read = open ( path, 'r')                                    
>>> print(read)                                                 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='ports.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> 
>>> exit()
```

You have to give either relative path or absolute path.And your code you are missing `/` before `root` and so interpreter unable to find the file at given path.

Relative path:

```
$ ls ports.txt                                                  
ports.txt
```

Absolute path:

```
$ readlink -f ports.txt                                         
/c/Users/rgenupula/ports.txt
```